# Database table structure for price list

Tags: database, structure

I have like about 10 tables where are records with date ranges and some value belongin to the date range.

Each table has some meaning.

For example

rates

```
    start_date DATE
    end_date DATE
    price DOUBLE
```

availability

```
    start_date DATE
    end_date DATE 
    availability INT
```

and then table dates

```
     day DATE
```

where are dates for each day for 2 years ahead.

Final result is joining these 10 tables to dates table. 
The query takes a bit longer, because there are some other joins and subqueries.

I have been thinking about creating one bigger table containing all the 10 tables data for each day, but final table would have about 1.5M  - 2M records.

From testing it seems to be quicker (0.2s instead of about 1s) to search in this table instead of joining tables and searching in the joined result.

Is there any real reason why it should be bad idea to have a table with that many records?

The final table would look like

```
    day DATE 
    price DOUBLE 
    availability INT
```

Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a complicated question.  The answer depends heavily on usage patterns.  Presumably, most of the values do not change every day.  So, you could be vastly increasing the size of the database.

On the other hand, something like availability may change every day, so you already have a large table in your database.

If your usage patterns focused on one table at a time, I'd be tempted to say "leave well-enough alone".  That is, don't make a change if it ain't broke.  If your usage involved multiple updates to one type of record, I'd be inclined to leave them in separate tables (so locking for one type of value does not block queries on other types).

However, your usage suggests that you are combining the tables.  If so, I think putting them in one row per day per item makes sense.  If you are getting successive days at one time, you may find that having separate days in the underlying table greatly simplifies your queries.  And, if your queries are focused on particular time frames, your proposed structure will keep the relevant data in the cache, giving room for better performance.

I appreciate what Bohemian says.  However, you are already going to the lowest level of granularity and seeing that it works for you.  I think you should go ahead with the reorganization.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I decided to do the reorganization.

Answer (score 0):

I went down this road once and regretted it.

The fact that you have a projection of millions of rows tells me that dates from one table don't line up with dates from another table, leading to creating extra boundaries for some attributes because being in one table all attributes must share the same boundaries.

The problem I encountered was that the business changed and suddenly I had a lot more combinations to deal with and the number of rows blew right out, slowing queries significantly. The other problem was keeping the data up to date - my "super" table was calculated from the separate tables when ever they changed.

I found that keeping them separate and moving the logic into the app layer worked for me.

The data I was dealing with was almost exactly the same as yours except I had only 3
 tables: I had availability, pricing and margin. The fact was that the 3 were unrelated, so date ranges never aligned, leasing to lots of artificial rows in the big table.

Comment: Well, in my case all data are related and there is a record for each day in almost every table and in final i do joins resulting in almost  same huge table, but there is some where condition which reduces that size. Something like SELECT * FROM days LEFT JOIN rates ON rates.start_date >= day AND rates.end_date <= day LEFT JOIN availability ON availability.start_date >= day AND availability.end_date <= day ... etc. I just can't get off the feeling that this is redundant and I can store it all into one table, but bigger one. I'm afraid just only a performance.

Comment: In that case I would change my table design to have a single date  column rather than a range. Even though this will mean repeated data for some consecutive days, the joins will be much faster because the join is done on a simple equals comparison, rather than a between match, especially if you put an index on the date column. That will keep your data model sane and still give you great performance.